# ArcGIS server Geoprocessing job failed immediately after submit

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, update

I have a few geoprocessing services published onto a production ArcGIS server but after a series of Windows 2012R2 and ArcGIS server updates, the services stopped function.

When I submit a job, these are the messages I would get:

- esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Submitted.
- esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Executing...
- esriJobMessageTypeError:
- esriJobMessageTypeError: Failed.

To test and see if there is something wrong with the server, I published an empty python script. When I submit a job to that service, I get the same set of message. If it had function normally, there wouldn't be any "esriJobMessageTypeError". Its as if the code did not execute at all, stopped at the first line.

Does anyone have similar problems after updates and any fixes?

---

UPDATE
Attempting to built my service from scratch step by step and I think I have located where the problem started.

Starting from the beginning,

1. Published an empty python script to a test python service and confirmed that it is running normally.
2. Update the script with some imports. Service is executing normally.
3. Update the service with one input parameter. The service failed with the above 4 lines of esriJobMessag. However server log did not record anything

---

UPDATE
Have test the empty script with a single parameter on another ArcGIS server and the server execute the service with no problem.

So what should I do next? Anything before completely re-install the problem ArcGIS server?

Comment: The message level for this service is "Info"

Comment: Try this patch: https://support.esri.com/en/download/7576 ? Although, you wouldnt even be able to publish a new GP  service if this was indeed your problem.

Comment: Debugging service failures usually requires a great deal of messaging code within the service code, and changing the Server logging level to support Verbose logging. We do not have a fraction of the information needed to help answer the question as written.

Comment: I really don't have any other information. I literally published an empty python script and still got those exact 4 lines of messages. WIll try the patch and update on what happened.

Comment: Hi KHibma. The patch did not work. There is just no information. I check the log in the management portal and all it said in Verbose mode is was "SEVERE Jun 18, 2018, 8:50:43 AM Error executing tool. <Service Name> Job ID: j25facd72254643cd9e9e5e320cbbdd87 <Service Path>". Where else can I get more detailed debugging information?

Comment: Did you change the log level to debug level under settings, then try executing the GP service?  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_zVUM0YExQYUzobz2Q4xFxWpK81LylDApeKwo5ZAQDo/edit

Comment: Hi Kirk. Just made the changes to the settings. Still have no log. I wish I have more info to go on, but I'm actually losing debugging info. Still have no idea which patch update caused this breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I don't think it happened from the same reason, however, adding a relatively general solution for anyone else stumbling here.

My problem started happening after an ArcGIS Server update to version 10.61, it happened because my python script used a *.mxd file that was in a folder that wasn't registered as a data source.

So my script ran locally but failed instantly when used as a service.

I found the problem using two logging solutions:

1. the service log which even when instructed to log at the `INFO` level only logged errors. Inside the relevant log I found the python stack trace.
   You can find the services logs in your server machine (under Windows) at `C:\arcgisserver\logs\{server name}\services\`.
   There you have to navigate to the directory of the specific service and find the most recently updated log file.
   I found there that my jobs failed because the server could not find the *.mxd file that the script had to use.
   [image: top black square hides the service name, middle the service name in the server directories which house the script and the bottom the file name]
2. After I knew where my script failed, I added custom logging using the `logging` module. which helped me find where the server was looking for the *.mxd (in a folder that doesn't exist.

This is a basic configuration for logging inside the script:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join('D:/{whatever folder you want logs in}','{log file name.txt/.log}'), 
                level=logging.INFO, 
                format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and every where you would want to log an INFO level message, just add:

```
logging.info('your message')
```

This was my resulting log and how I found that the server used the wrong path.
line 2 is from a local script activation through ArcMap, line 4 is when used through the gpservice.

[image: line 2 is from a local script activation through ArcMap, line 4 is when used through the gpservice]

I hope this will help anyone in logging your gp scripts.